# Continuation Four in a row game

Tags: powershell

I figured the array out, but now I want to Write-host the value of my $CreateGrid[1,1] for example to

```
Write-host "  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J " 
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 1"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 2"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 3"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 4"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 5"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 6"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 7"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 8"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 9"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
Write-host "| $CreateGrid[1,1] |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 10"
Write-host "+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ "
```

However when I try this, I get the following output for the value:

```
(          System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[]             Syst
em.Object[] System.Object[]                   System.Object[]                                                 [1,1])
```

How would I go around this? or is there a more clever way? 
In short I want to include the positional value of the array in the Grid shown above.

EDIT:

```
$CreateBoard = New-object "Array[,]" 10,10

Function Add-ToColumn{
param ([Int] $columnnum,[String] $player)

    PROCESS{if (0..9 -notcontains $columnnum){"Invalid move";return}
        #0 is the bottom, 9 is the top
        for($i = 0; $i -le 9; $i++)
        {
            if ($CreateBoard[$columnnum, $i] -eq $null)
            {
                $CreateBoard[$columnnum, $i] = $player
                "Coin placed in $columnnum, $i coins in the column!"
                return
            }
        }
        #if you get here, column is full
        "Invalid move"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put an expression in a double quoted string, the parser stops at the first non-variable name character. So:

```
"$CreateGrid[1,1]"
```

is processed as if it were

```
"$CreateGrid" + "[1,1]"
```

and as `$CreateGrid` is (or at least appears to be) an array it performs a `ToString` on each member and concatenates the results (as this is a two dimensional array, each enumerated member is an array, hence `System.Object[]` multiple times).

If you use the expression syntax (`$(...)`) inside the string the whole contained expression is processed as a PowerShell expression (eg. you can put a pipeline in there):

```
"$($CreateGrid[1,1])"
```

Comment: Alright, when I input that, I get the following error:
Write-host "$($CreateGrid[1,1])"
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:36 char:15
+ Write-host "$($CreateGrid[1,1])"
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: So `$CreateGrid` is null: that's a different problem.

Comment: @SiemHermans At a quick glance that looks OK. Suggest running through the debugger (console or ISE) to check the value of `$CreateGrid` before dereferencing. (Likely some other code is messing things up.)

Comment: Well, this pretty much is all the code on the screen, apart from the 'Add-Column 1 red' line to specify the contents. I am however running Powershell V1.0. Does that pose a problem?

Comment: Nevermind, the same problem occurs when I use Powershell v3.0